# Return an object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm suddenly stuck. I defined an object:

```
public class AddResult
{
   public AddResult(string id, bool success)
   {
      this.ID = id;
      this.Success = success;
   }

   public string ID { get; set; } 
   public bool Success { get; set; } 
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } 
}
```

I want to return this object in another method.

```
public AddResult Load(string userName, string password)
{
    // validate
    if(userName = "")
      {
           AddResult.ErrorMessage = "wrong";
           AddResult.ID = "";
      }
    // want to return object AddResult
 }
```

The intellisense is not working for AddResult.ID etc, I know something is wrong but need your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate an object of the class `AddResult`, your code should look like this:

```
var addResult = new AddResult("", false) { ErrorMessage = "wrong" };
return addResult;
```

Comment: Should I define the method as public object Load(...) rather than public AddResult?

Comment: No the return type of the method should be of the instantiated object not a generic object.

Comment: I'd rather return an `AddResult` instance than an `object` because you won't be able to access its fields without casting otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
AddResult.ID = "";
```

but in this case, *ID* must be [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, you can create object of *AddResult* class:

```
AddResult addResult = new AddResult();
```

And access *ID* from *addResult* object, like this:

```
addResult.ID = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    public AddResult Load(string userName, string password)
    {
        AddResult addResult = null;
        // validate
        if (userName == "")
        {
            addResult = new AddResult("", false) { ErrorMessage = "wrong" };
        }
        // want to return object AddResult

        return addResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define ID as static :

```
public static string ID { get; set; }
```

and use it this way :

```
AddResult.ID = 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var addResult = new AddResult("", false) { ErrorMessage = "wrong" };
return addResult as AddResult;
```

Comment: Converting var to class object

Comment: I was suggesting that you actually edit your post with an explanation of how your code work. I do understand what it does.